# Libvirtd start error

Tags: libvirt, opennebula

I had to remove libvirt manually using kill. Now when I'm trying to start libvirtd it says  `error: Unable to initialize network sockets. Check /var/log/messages or run without --daemon for more info.`

I tried running /usr/sbin/libvirtd and it works fine except that there is no network.
I had some VMs running while killing the libvirt which was launched before the installation of opennebula. Later I noticed that opennebula had changed the user and group of qemu.conf to oneadmin. So I suspect that some of the remains of previous VM still exist.

Answer (score 3):

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/The_daemon_cannot_be_started

By default libvirtd wants to listen with tls enabled, but if you're not using tls (doing sasl perhaps) you'll need to explicitly disable tls in libvirtd.conf by setting "listen_tls" to 0.

Comment: and remember the obvious that I overlooked, add that to libvirtd.conf, not libvirt.conf